# How do I fix this domain settings?

Tags: dns, cpanel

i have added up domain in my cpanel and have setup dns record in my domain settings.. but problem is that when I open http://example.com it opens up http://example.com/domain.com. Please help.

Comment: Rule excerpt: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* and: *Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.*

Comment: Please ask this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

I can see it's not server wide issues, There is an issues with the your .htaccess file OR your application (Website scripts) URL setting. You will have to check that setting.

Comment: thanks sorry i answered late on this but yes it was htaccess issue. Thanks